# Web Crawlers detecting published pages with "closed" status.

Tags: channel-entries

I want to begin using the page scheduler to set the "closed" status to pages to "open" once a specific date comes. My question is, will web crawlers still be able to find published pages if the entry status = "Closed"?

Comment: Did any of the suggestions help? If so, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

In EE content lives in Channels Entries - do you mean Channel Entries rather than Pages in your post?

For channel entries, if you make the channel entry status equal to 'closed' normally anything external to EE won't see it (page crawlers included).  Similarly if you set the publish dates for an entry it won't be shown to anything external except during the period that the publish dates are valid.

As with most things in EE a lot depends on how your templates are designed - as it is possible to override or change the behaviour attached to 'open' / 'closed' status and regarding publish dates - so if you want some unusual behaviour regarding these two elements you can program it into your template design.

A "Page" in EE normally refers to a channel entry tied to a specific URL form that overrides the standard routing protocols for a channel entry within EE.  Content set up using the Page feature will follow same logic as for a Channel Entry with regard to publish dates (which also can be over-ridden within the Template design if required).

If by "Page" you mean EE content created with something like "Structure" (an add-on that makes EE behave a bit like Wordpress) I guess you need to check its documentation, but I'd imagine it would follow normal patterns.

If you want to show some content to web crawlers that you don't show to visitors (?why?) I guess you could set up some logic within your template to sniff for the User Agent string and send different information to the crawler as required.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In theory they shouldn't be accessible but I have sometimes come across it when the URL is still there but with no content.

This can be overcome by adding this into your entries loop.

{if no_results}
{redirect="404"}
{/if}

So if there are no entries in the loop, or all or set to closed then you will get redirected to your 404 page.